# At second approach, second spinner value is not changing

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have used two spinners for dept and course in which I am setting courses of respective depts. 
When I try to select department again it is showing respective courses in the second spinner but not changing the displayed value of the second spinner.

I tried clearing my string array as a second option but it's still not working.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, depts);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
DeptSpin.setAdapter(adapter);
DeptSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, courses);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
courseSpin.setAdapter(adapter1);
courseSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    courses.clear();
    courses.add("Select Course");
    Cursor cursor = HostelDB.getCourse(position - 1);
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            courses.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()) after you have add all the items:

```
courses.clear();
courses.add("Select Course");

...
// refresh the adapter
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```